# AdMob not working in production (Android)

Tags: android, admob, banner

I have tested my banner ad in test mode and it worked perfectly, after that I registered the app in AdMob, changed the unit ID and the build method and it simply doesn't work. I get "Failed to load Ad 0" Every time.

**manifest:**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

**loading ad:**

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

**layout:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

**unit id:**

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-*************/*********</string>
```

**taken from here: (After registering my app)**

[image: ad_unit_id]
**log:**

> 04-30 16:44:08.586 21345-21395/--------- W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>   04-30 16:44:08.591 21345-21345/--------- W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I guess it take some time to show up ad in your app

Comment: @prathamkesarkar That's not the problem, I've waited for too long and it shows an error loading ad (as I said).

Comment: can you post the log

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Have you given ad a minimum height and width

Comment: It's some 320 x 520 I guess

Comment: Did u tried clicking your own ad cause that will void that admob ID and ban your account

Comment: It's working if I use the test ID, so it's not a layout problem. And no, I haven't clicked the ad (because it doesn't show in production mode).

Comment: I guess you need to contact with their support service might be some issue with your account

Comment: Are you using correct version of the adunit

Comment: dude I finally found it  check if this work use ads tag instead of app

Comment: You can name it as you want, thats not a problem. I finally found the solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have waited a few hours more and it is finally working. It seems that the generated id in AdMob takes some time to be "validated" and usable.

Comment: Exactly as @prathamkesarkar told you originally

Comment: I didn't understand the same.